# Как добавить два объекта в json файл, используя php?

Tags: php, json

Я такой вопрос уже задавал. Но, дело в другом. Да, несколько объектов добавляются в JSON файл, но валидатор ругается. Сейчас объясню почему. Вот код, как добавляю два объекта в файл.

```
file_put_contents('js/allProducts.json',json_encode($json1, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
file_put_contents('js/allProducts.json',json_encode($json2, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), FILE_APPEND);
```

Но, вот как отображается у меня в JSON файле.

```
[{
    "Id": "010",
    "Title": "Милый дом 100мл",
    "Price": "210",
    "ImgSrc": "standart_candle.jpg",
    "Description_1": "бергамот, чистый хлопок",
    "Description_2": "пион, лаванда, морские ноты, петигрен",
    "Description_3": "мускус, сандаловое дерево",
    "Count": "40"
}]
[{
    "Id": "110",
    "Title": "Candle box набор 100мл",
    "Price": "320",
    "Description_1": "Коробочка, для создания аромасвечи своими руками.",
    "Description_2": "Создайте свечу самостоятельно, чтобы ещё больше наслаждаться моментом зажжения.",
    "ImgSrc": "new_category.jpg",
    "Count": "20"
 }]
```

Оно вставляется в файл JSON как два отдельных объекта. Как мне объединить в один используя PHP?

Comment: `json_encode([$json1, $json2])`

Comment: то есть попробовать так?                        
file_put_contents('js/allProducts.json',json_encode([$json1, $json2], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));